# How to delete a user defined node in a linked list?

Tags: c++

This code is supposed to be a library management system where the user can choose from a menu to either add a book, print the list of books added or delete a book. My add and print functions work. However, my delete function does not. Once multiple books are added, the user can choose a specific book and insert its name and it will get deleted.

In efforts to delete a specific book, i made a new string and the user can input the name of the book they want to delete. Then I ran a while loop that goes through the nodes until it finds in which node that book name exists and deletes it.

// struct for book information

```
struct Book
{

  string Name;
  string Author;
  string Publisher;
  string Year;
  string ISBN;
  Book *next;
};

// delete function 

void deleteBook (Book * &, Book * &)
{
  if (head == NULL) // condition when no books are added
    {
      cout << " Empty List" << endl; 
    }
  else if (head == last) // if one book is added
    {
      delete head;
      head = NULL;
      last = NULL;
    }
  else
    {
      cout << "Please Enter The Name of The Book You Wish to Delete: " <<
    endl;
      string n;
      cin >> n;
      while (last->Name != n) // to delete a specific book 
    {
      Book *temp = new Book;
      temp = last;
      last=last->next;
      delete temp;
    }
    }
}
```

for example: The user adds a book named "Math"
and then chooses the delete option from menu
the user then inserts the book "Math", the node containing that book gets deleted.

however every time i test that i get a segmentation fault error

Comment: I took it out and it still get the same error. I am deleting the the specified node but i am not re-linking the head to the last to fill the gap.

Comment: Why did you put it in there in the first place?

Comment: Why do you use `while (last->Name != n)` to search for the book name the user entered. You should start at head e.g. by setting `temp = head;` before while-loop. And you need to check if the pointer to list node is not `nullptr`before you access `node->Name`. Otherwise if book name is not in list you finally will try to access `Name` via `last->next` which is a `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

See First thing. 
I didn't get why are you using last in your while loop. You should use head( temp) for searching name is the list . 
Here for sake of simplicity I'm assuming that struct has only two members name of the book and next pointer.

```
Book *temp = head;
//Check base condition by yourself 
while(temp->next->name != Name && temp->next != NULL) // this will go until we reach 1 one node before the main node which you need.Suppose your book is at 5th position it'll stop at 4th.
Book *temp2 = temp->next; // it will point to the node you want to delete ie  temp2 is 5th node and temp  is 4th nod.
// Now just do linking 
temp->next = temp2->next; // in 4th's next store 5th's next 
delete(temp2); //assuming you are in c++ or use free() if in C.
```

Comment out if you didn't understand any part.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. However, when i was testing this, it will always delete the node before the chosen one. if i choose the 4th book, the program deletes the 3rd book and so on... any suggestions?

Comment: @MohamedAliMohamedAdem See what you are saying are two different concepts . there are two types of deletion in basic 
1. Delete by position- it means you provide position of the node.
No matter what it contain it will delete that node.
like if 2->3->4->70->6->NULL. you will give n = 3; and result will be
2->3->70->6->NULL
2. Deletion by value - it means you provide value or data you want.
Now suppose you gave 70.it give search for it and delete it
2->3->4->6->NULL . this will be the result.
Now tell which kind of deletion you are looking for. Then i'll explain